# DataGrid ScrollViewer not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013, scrollviewer

Not able to scroll the data in `DataGrid` with keyboard arrow keys.
`ScrollViewer_KeyDown` event is working fine when using with `Grid` but not getting invoke when used with datagrid default `ScrollViewer`.

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
     <Style TargetType="ScrollViewer">
          <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>                
          <EventSetter Event="KeyDown" Handler="ScrollViewer_KeyDown"></EventSetter>
     </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Code

```
private void ScrollViewer_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Handled) return;
    var temporaryEventArgs =
          new KeyEventArgs(e.KeyboardDevice, e.InputSource, e.Timestamp, e.Key)
    {
        RoutedEvent = e.RoutedEvent
    };
    // This line avoids it from resulting in a stackoverflowexception
    if (sender is ScrollViewer) return;
    ((ScrollViewer)sender).RaiseEvent(temporaryEventArgs);
    e.Handled = temporaryEventArgs.Handled;
}
```

Comment: Use the `PreviewKeyDown` event. I believe `DataGrid` handles the `KeyDown` event to change the selection of rows (if arrow up/down was pressed).

Comment: Thanks but its not working.

Comment: Is your handler executed? Did you try setting a breakpoint in it?

Comment: Tried using Breakpoint . Handler is not getting executed.

Comment: Could it be that there is something else that handles the event?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
<Grid FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=MyScrollViewer}">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="MyScrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">            
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        </DataGrid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

No need to handle any events.  The key is to make sure the scrollviewer has the focus by setting the FocusManager.FocusedElement.

Comment: Actually I want show the scroll bar inside the DataGrid. the way you have suggested is working fine however its showing the scroll bar outside the DataGrid

Comment: You can use the DataGrid ScrollViewer (the way you originally had it) and then make sure the DataGrid has the focus.  The only caveat is that then a row gets focus and your down arrow click moves down a row.